# Increasing and decreasing the quantity of products function

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

I have a problem with my increasing and decreasing quantity function. Increasing the quantity works great, however decreasing it spoils it. I click plus, for example, 19 times, then I click minus and 19 becomes 0.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
const itemQuantitySystem = () => {
  let minus = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity .minus");
  let plus = document.querySelectorAll(".quantity .plus");
  
  plus.forEach(e => {
    let quantity = 1;
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
      let number = e.previousElementSibling;
      quantity++;
      number.innerHTML = quantity;
    })
  })
  
  minus.forEach(e => {
    let quantity = parseInt(e.nextElementSibling.textContent);
    e.addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log(quantity)
      let number = e.nextElementSibling;
      quantity--;
      number.innerHTML = quantity;
    })
  })
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="quantity">
    <div class="minus">-</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="plus">+</div>
</div>
```

[image: Increasing]
[image: Decreasing]

In the photos, immediately after clicking the minus sign, 19 becomes 0, then -1, -2, then I click the plus button and it becomes 20.

I tried to place variables in other places, but nothing helped.

Comment: You have two independent `quantity` variables, one for each button.

Answer (score 1):

You have two independent `quantity` variables, one for each button. You'll need a shared one, one for each `div.quantity`:

```js
for (const systemElement of document.querySelectorAll(".quantity")) {
  const number = systemElement.querySelector(".number");
  const minus = systemElement.querySelector(".minus");
  const plus = systemElement.querySelector(".plus");
  
  let quantity = parseInt(number.textContent);

  plus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    quantity++;
    number.textContent = quantity;
  });

  minus.addEventListener("click", () => {
    quantity--;
    number.textContent = quantity;
  });
}
```

```css
.quantity {
  display: flex;
}
.quantity .number {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="quantity">
    <button class="minus">-</button>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <button class="plus">+</button>
</div>
```